# Creating arrays to separate speakers in a dialogue and then counting the words that each specific person said.

Tags: arrays, vb.net, string

I am trying to create a program that will take a dialogue and separate it into speakers and then count how many words they said throughout the dialogue.

Consider the following example;

GEORGE

Today we will be talking about this topic.

MARY

That is a very interesting topic.

GEORGE

Okay, let's get started.

ROB

This is relevant in many different situations.

So, I want the output from this to be:

GEORGE

total words: 12

MARY

total words: 6

ROB

total words: 7

At this point, the only thing I know is that I need to create an array that will fill with UPPERCASE names and then use it to separate the dialogue by speaker so that the words can be counted up.

Any help will be greatly appreciated, I am familiar with arrays, but I have very little experience with string analysis and manipulation.

Comment: Read the docs: [Arrays in Visual Basic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wak0wfyt.aspx) and [String.Split Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably don't want to use an array - a [`Dictionary(Of String, Integer)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) would be a better choice for storing the word counts per speaker.  The code would be somethings like this:

```
Dim wordCounts As Dictionary(Of String, Integer) = new Dictionary(Of String, Integer)()
Dim currentSpeaker As String = Nothing

For Each line As String In File.ReadLines(dialogueFile)
    If line.Trim().Length > 0 AndAlso line.Trim() = line.Trim().ToUpper() Then
        ' Upper case lines are speakers
        currentSpeaker = line.Trim()
    Else
        If currentSpeaker Is Nothing Then
            Throw New Exception("No Speaker!")
        End If
        Dim wordCount As Integer = line.Split(New String() {" "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length
        If wordCounts.ContainsKey(currentSpeaker) Then
            wordCounts(currentSpeaker) += wordCount
        Else
            wordCounts.Add(currentSpeaker, wordCount)
        End If
    End If
Next

For Each count As KeyValuePair(Of String, Integer) In wordCounts
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", count.Key, count.Value)
Next
```

Which would output the following, as you wanted:

```
GEORGE: 12
MARY: 6
ROB: 7
```

Comment: Thank you, but I am having trouble displaying the results. I'm not familiar with console.writeline and was wondering if it was possible to just assign the dictionary components to a textbox on the form. Also, a bit more specific, is it possible to alter this to count total words and to count specific words that I could choose at any time. For instance, could I count how many times each speaker said "today", which in this case would show up as 1 for GEORGE and zero for the other two. I have no experience with string and use vb for mainly math.. Thank you, for any future help as well!

Comment: Never mind on the displaying question, I was able to program that fine. I have an understanding of the use of the dictionary now, but I can't figure out have to read the string and match it to a specified word.

Comment: For counting specific words, create a variable for the words - `Dim words = line.Split(New String() {" "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)` and then loop through the words using `For Each word In words`. You will need somewhere to store the per-word counts, so you'll probably want a class that has the total count and the per-word counts (as a `Dictionary(Of String, Integer)`), and use that in the `wordCounts` dictionary. Give it a go and post specific questions (with code) if you run into difficulties - Stack Overflow isn't a place where people do your work for free! ;-)